# Higher dimensional analog of a rational elliptic surface: reference request

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Consider two triples of lines $L_0, L_1, L_2$ and $M_0, M_1, M_2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2.$ A blow up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at 9 points $L_i \cap M_j$ is a rational elliptic surface, a very well understood object in algebraic geometry.

Here is a natural higher dimensional generalization. Consider $2n+2$ hyperplanes
$L_0, \ldots, L_n$ and $M_0, \ldots, M_n$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ in general position. A blow up of $\mathbb{P}^n$ at $(n+1)^2$ codimension $2$ subspaces $L_i \cap M_j$ is a rational variety, which admits a structure of a Calabi-Yau fibration over $\mathbb{P}^1.$

**Question:** What is known about sections and singular fibers of this fibration? What is known about the structure of the Mori cone of this space?

This must be a well understood object, I will be very grateful for any references.